# no-flexbox not showing in IE9 modernizr

Tags: flexbox, internet-explorer-9, modernizr

I'm using flexbox and have installed modernizr to combat it not working in IE9, however it works fine and shows either flexbox or no-flexbox in IE8-11 but in IE9 it doesn't show either.

I did a quick test and shows modernizr is working;

```
if (Modernizr.flexbox) {
    // supported
    console.log('Yes');
} else {
    // not-supported
    console.log('No');      
}
```

And it came back as No for IE9 like expected.

Has anyone got any ideas why it's not working, apologies if it's something obvious I've missed something.